# Notification when Azure database matching a defined name is still running

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I want to receive a notification when there is an Azure database running that matches a defined name pattern. What script can I use to check for existence of a database by name pattern?

For example when are debugging live issues we will often use the **Copy** feature from Azure to back up our production database onto a dev server. The databases are always named with a ***_copy** suffix. Occasionally we forget to delete these databases when we are finished with them, so they continue to be billed.

We would like a daily notification if there are any running ***_copy** databases running.

Comment: You could write a timer triggered azure function that checks for running databases, or a logic app....

Comment: @PeterBons thanks for taking the time to respond. I'm looking for some more specific instructions to save me a couple of days research on what I'm sure is a very simple script

Comment: I somehow doubt someone is going to write it for you, and I also doubt there is something out-of-the box in azure.

Answer (score 1):

The script below will give you a list of databases with "copy" at the end of the name. Put it inside a Runbook to send you a daily report of the databases.

```
$ListServers = Get-AzSqlServer | Select-Object ResourceGroupName, ServerName
Foreach ($Server in $ListServers){
    Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $Server.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $Server.ServerName `
        | Where-Object {$_.DatabaseName -like "*copy"} `
        | Select-Object ResourceId
    }
```